# Umbraco: Build a custom field type (Forms) with a dropdown that renders different choice depending on selected

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7, umbraco-forms

[image]

Is this possible? enter image description here

Add this custom field type for a form.

Checkboxes changes depending on which selected option is chosen on the dropdown.

Comment: Is the image that you're showing supposed to be the Umbraco backoffice or the view output?